# Installing Mathematica 10 in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, mathematica

I want to install and run Mathematica in Ubuntu. The things I have done so far are as below. Could anyone help me to complete installing and running Mathematica?

Things I have typed in terminal are here:

[image: things I have typed in terminal is here]

Second picture is the folder of Mathematica.

[image]

Comment: Is this software genuine? There's a folder in your second picture that kind of suggests otherwise.

Comment: change directory then run `chmod +x Mathematica.sh`  and `Mathematica.sh`